# CEF display current window

Tags: chromium-embedded

so i'm a beginner with CEF and i wanted to ask you people, if it's possible to draw an html file with CEF on the current window 
The thing is that I don't have the executable source so i'm injecting a DLL in it.

So is it possible to inject a DLL in a program to display an html on the current window using CEF.If so, with which function?

Thank you in advance,
swiftiq

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the hWnd window handle, you can open the CEF browser into it.
CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser() takes a CefWindowInfo as the first parameter. Use CefWindowInfo::SetAsChild() to set the desired window.